# Почему не выводит данные в jsp ($id, $name..)

Tags: java, jsp

Не выводит данные из List
Servlet

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Flower> flowers = flowerBusinessService.getFlowers();
    //HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); //Убрать true
    //session.setAttribute("flowers", flowers);
    request.setAttribute("flowers", flowers);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/flowers.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

JSP:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="com.be.entity.Flower"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flowershop.css">
    <title>Flowers</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${flowers}" var="fl" varStatus="rowStatus">
            <tr>
                <td>${fl.id}</td>
                <td>${fl.name}</td>
                <td>${fl.price}</td>
                <td>${fl.quantity}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
<button type="button" name="back" class="submit-button" onclick="history.back()">back</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Вывод:

[image: Хех]

Comment: может `response.setAttribute("flowers", flowers);` ?

Comment: У него нет такого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:
Проверить web.xml на присутствие

```html
<web-app
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
```